# What does 班 in 工作专班 mean?

Tags: word

工作专班 or XX专班 has become a buzz word in recent news reports of China's media. It sounds like a task force or a group of people handling a specific matter but has never been so used earlier. The word 班 is especially ambiguous, the usual alternative for which is 小组. The case in which 班 is used not intended for the class or form of a school is 领导班子, which is as confusing.

Comment: The latest news report in which this phrase is in use: 南京玄奘寺供奉侵华日军战犯牌位事件，深深刺痛国人，严重伤害民族感情，令人震惊、无比愤慨。南京市委市政府连夜成立工作专班调查处置，通报初步情况，对有关单位和部门责任人员进行严肃处理。

Answer (score 2):

班 in 工作专班 means 班组。

> 班组是在劳动分工的基础上，把生产过程中相互协同的同工种工人、相近工种或不同工种工人组织在一起，从事生产活动的一种组织。

Comment: In the recent hot cases in China, I believe all those people involved are high-ranking officials, not the workmen at lower level as you mention.

Comment: @NanningYouth In fact, 班组 is more commonly used for workmen, although the word itself carries no connotations in ranking. E.g. 三班倒 and 领导班子.

Comment: @iBug 班子 is first used to describe lowly opera or drama guys, but why later is used for leadership is beyond me. Perhaps leaders all love beautiful actresses, LOL.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I thought 工作专班 refers to ***the peculiar bus we take to work***, where 班 is short for 班车. This is because that's the most common use of the phrase in my experience.

After reading along explanations, the sense OP posted can work too.

Comment: I did not notice this phrase until recently when there were incidents of women-beating, rural bank runs, movie star recruited to public-funded theatre

Answer (score 1):

"专班" is an agency responsible for implementing
where "班" is another form of "小组", which is usually larger than "小组"
A similar meaning application of "班" is "一班人马", which means a group of people